# transparent regions in 3D plots (flat semi-circle)

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, opacity

I am trying to plot one (or two) flat semi circles that are filled, and the filling is transparent.

Looking at some examples online I have come up with the following:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{10 Cos[u], v, -10 Sin[u]}, {v, 10 Cos[u], -10 Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0.1, -0.1}] /. Line[l_List] :> {{Opacity[0.1], Red, Polygon[l]}, {Black, Line[l]}}
```

Which gives me the following figure:

[image]

While this is great, it is not possible to see through the regions. For example, one cannot see one of the semi-circles through the other. And If I put any other 3D object in there, it is also hidden by the region. So while Opacity makes the red shade lighter, it is not transparent.

Any idea of how to make this transparent/translucid?

Does not need to be parametric, as long as it is 3D will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Reply to the Comment**

Given a fixed point `{x0,y0,z0}` and a parametric space curve `h[u_]:={10 Cos[u], 0, 10 Sin[u]}`, we can construct lines from `{x0,y0,z0}` to `h[u]` by `{x0,y0,z0}+ t*(h[u]-{x0,y0,z0})`, here `0<=t<=1`, that is the way to construct such surface.

**Original**

```
f[u_, t_] := {0, 0, 1} + t*{10 Cos[u], 0, -10 Sin[u]};
g[u_, t_] := {0, 0, 1} + t*{0, 10 Cos[u], -10 Sin[u]};
ParametricPlot3D[{f[u, t], g[u, t]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Opacity[.5]}, {Green, Opacity[.5]}}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Gray}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

We can change the center of semi-circle and the range of `u` to get another semi-circle.

```
f[u_, t_] := {0, 0, 0} + t*({10 Cos[u], 0, 10 Sin[u]}-{0,0,0});
g[u_, t_] := {0, 0, 0} + t*({0, 10 Cos[u], 10 Sin[u]}-{0,0,0});
ParametricPlot3D[{f[u, t], g[u, t]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Opacity[.5]}, {Green, Opacity[.5]}}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Gray}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So this is a bit strange, to me at least; can you clarify if this is successful due to the use of two separate surfaces/regions?

Comment: @CATrevillian Use two parametrics to construct a surface. See the  updated.

Comment: That worked out amazingly. thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
SliceContourPlot3D[ x^2 + y^2 + z^2,
 {x == 0, y == 0}, 
 {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[], 
 Contours -> {{1}}, 
 ContourShading -> Opacity[.5, Red], 
 BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Black},
 RegionFunction -> (#3 >= 0 &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One more hackneyed way repurposing some old code that had very short cylinders.

```
Graphics3D[
 {{Orange, Opacity[0.1], EdgeForm[Thick], 
   Cylinder[{{1, 1, 0.99}, {1, 1, 1}}, 1]},
  {Blue     , Opacity[0.1], EdgeForm[Thick], 
   Cylinder[{{0.99, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, 1]}},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
 ImageSize -> 450,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}}
 ]
```

[image]